# Issue Lightning component deploying from Dev to Devpro Sandbox

Tags: lightning-aura-components, summer-16

i found one weird issue is , when I migrated Lightning Components from Developer to Developer pro sand box there is completely discrepancy between two orgs in look and feel wise and functional wise lot of SLDS styles are not working e.g. input Date component giving old fashioned Date selector.

and also please let me know what is `ltnglocker` CSS which displaying in main container DIV class.

Comment: as in other thread suggested , we have issue with Summer 16 for scrolling, container size (e.g. I pad is fully occupying container size) and  InputDate style those are i have faced.